# How call controller action from separate jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to separate jquery that I have at the top of MVC view and put it in separate  jquery file. I have several Ajax call in this jquery code that call the action in controller, how should I replace this line with:

currently "GetInfo" is name of action and "Customer" is Name of controller.

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Customer")'
```

with this way was working when the code is at the top of the view but when I put it in separate jquery file it is not go to the controller code at all.

and this is my complete Ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Customer")',

        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            if (data && data.data) {
                $.unblockUI();
                renderResults(data.data);

            }
            else {
                $.unblockUI();
                var error = $('#errorNoRecord');
                error.show();
            }

        },
```

Comment: Options include add a global variable in the main page - `var url = '@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Customer")'` and then `url: url,` or passing the value to the function or including it in a `data-` attribute of the element your handling

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, what do you mean abut the main page? Controller or view?

Comment: In the main view (but I would recommend the last option - e.g. `<button data-url="@Url.Action(...)" ...>` and in the external file get it using `var url = $(this).data('url');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I still can get tot the method, this is my button: <button id="btnSearch" data-url="@Url.Action("GetInfo", "Customer")" class="btn btn-success search pull-left">Search</button> this is in jqery:    var url = $(this).data('url'); but nothing is in url

Comment: forgot to mention the jquery file in different folder if that change anything.

Comment: You have not given enough information. How are you triggering this function? If its `$('#btnSearch').click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); $.ajax({ url: url, ....` will work

Comment: @StephenMuecke great yes it works. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't expect to have to change your routing, you could use the literal URL "/Customer/GetInfo". Lazy coding though.